# Convert Multiple Arrays to one big multidimesional array and how to manipulate it

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

So I have these four arrays

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> licensePlates = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> mileage = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> engineHours = new ArrayList<>();
```

But returning them one by one is a hassle so I was wondering how I would go about making a multi-dimensional array to hold all these values instead. And also how I would go about adding something to them, for example, let's say I wanted to add an extra licence plate to the licence plate part of the multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Make a class.*  It is really a bad idea to try to shoehorn lists with different meanings into one big multidimensional list, or to try to have multiple lists "line up" like that.

```
 class Car {
   String name;
   String licensePlate;
   int mileage;
   int engineHours;
   ...constructor, getters...
}
List<Car> carList;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend [louis-wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman) approach of creating a class.
If you are looking for an alternative then you can take a look at [Guava's ListMultiMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html)

```
ListMultiMap<String, Object> multiDimArray = ArrayListMultiMap.create();
multiDimArray.put("names", "merc");
multiDimArray.put("mileage", 10);
multiDimArray.put("names", "bmw");
multiDimArray.put("mileage", 20);

// To retrieve the names lists:
List<String> names = multiDimArray.get("names");
```